# GIMP - How do I change UI DPI?

Tags: gimp, art

This is a problem I have been having recently. My screen size has a pretty high pixel density and, as a result, all of GIMP's icons are criminally small and very difficult to look at.

I've tried searching for ways to increase the screen size but all that shows up is how to scale images. Thing is I know how to change the image DPI but I want to know how to change the actual program's DPI, so that the icons are better suited to my computer screen.

Comment: This is more suitable for the superuser.com SE - unless you want to help us to design bigger icons, of course :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed this would be appropriate for this Stack Exchange.  what is superuser.com SE all about?

Comment: About the usage of software - which is what this question is about.

Comment: As for the text size, this worked for me: https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Menu-font-too-small-to-read?pid=17533#pid17533

In my case on Linux, `gtkrc` is located at `~/.config/GIMP/2.10/gtkrc`.

Comment: Note Gimp 2.99 (in beta) fixes many issues with HiDPI setups.

Answer (score 19):

A simple solution for GIMP 2.10 (both under Linux and Windows):

1. Go to "Edit → Preferences".
2. In the Preferences dialog, go to "Interface → Icon Theme".
3. From the dropdown at the bottom, choose "Use icon size from the theme" or "Custom icon size" (and in the latter case, choose your icon size with the slider below that).

The problem you describe happens because by default it's "Guess icon size from resolution", which considers only a resolution in the sense of "1920×1080 px" or the like, and not the physical or configured pixel *density* (DPI value) of the display. Worse, in a multi-screen setup it only considers the *combined* resolution, which is the resolution of a virtual screen of which each physical screens shows a certain part.

Comment: This only applies to a small set of UI elements. For example, this setting appears to have no impact on the size of icons for brush shape and hardness or the text, check boxes, and other controls for modifying tool options.

Answer (score 12):

I have gimp 2.8 on Windows 10 and this is what solved the small tool icons problem for me:
open **This PC > Local Disc (C:) > Program Files > GIMP 2 > bin**,
right click on **gimp-2.8**,
open **Properties**,
click on **Compatibility**.
On the **settings** options select: 
**Override high DPI scaling behaviour.**
**Scaling performed by**,
scroll and select **System**,
Apply,
OK

Comment: Yes, but that means that everything is bigger, including selection lines and such?

Comment: This kind defeats the whope point of having a High-DPI monitor for image manipulation though.

Comment: Having appropriately-sized UI elements does not defeat the point of a high-DPI screen. If your system is scaling up UI elements too much in this program, it is probably doing the same in other programs, and you need to change the scaling globally. Alternative solutions that increase just the size of tool icons leave many other elements unusably tiny. This is the only solution I have seen that works to make GIMP usable on my screens.

Comment: I don't fully understand what changing "scaling performed by" to "system" does, but I stumbled upon this Q/A while trying to figure out why the vanilla gimp UI was so blurry on my normal dpi (32 inch 2k) monitor. I desperately did what this answer says, and it actually did not change the size of the ui elements (which isn't what I wanted) but it completely fixed all of the problems I had with the resolution of the gimp editor.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the tool icons (brush, move, selection etc) of GIMP's UI can be configured in the `gtkrc` file.
Try find this line in `gtkrc` file:

```
GimpToolPalette::tool-icon-size   = <size>
```

Where `<size>` is an written identifier (instead of a number like you might expect), with names like

- `menu`
- `button`
- `large-toolbar`

I personally set my icon sizes to `button` which is bigger than the default (which I think is `menu`).
I think `large-toolbar` is the biggest.

So maybe try something like changing the line to:

```
GimpToolPalette::tool-icon-size = large-toolbar
```

Comment: I tried to find the GimpToolPalette section in this custom theme I downloaded but it doesn't seem to be there. :o

Comment: @EmeraldEelEntertainment GIMP uses cascading config files where entries in  your user `gtkrc` will override those in the system GIMP `gtkrc` so just try pasting the line into your `gtkrc` and see if that increases the icon size

Comment: I copied and pasted the line into the gtkrc file of the theme I downloaded, and change it to button. I reloaded Gimp but nothing has changed. :(

Comment: @EmeraldEelEntertainment what about using `large-toolbar`?

Comment: I will give that shot and see what happens.

Comment: Ah okay, so I changed it but no difference has been made.

Comment: I also forgot to mention my screen size has a large DPI. It's 3840 x 2160.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kevin Payne's themes with big icons: these are available and discussed [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-GIMP-2-8-Large-size-Icons-Themes).

Comment: I'll give it a shot! I was curious to ask because I used a custom flat icon theme.

Comment: Okay, I downloaded and applied the theme; the text us much clearer but the icons haven't changed in size too much.